# splitting an hash and writing it to csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, hash

I am trying to split an hash and writing it to different csv files but it throws error

```
def split(self,filehandler, delimiter=',', row_limit=1000,
            output_name_template='output_%s.csv', output_path='.', keep_headers=True):

        #reader = csv.reader(filehandler, delimiter=delimiter)
        current_piece = 1
        current_out_path = os.path.join(
            output_path,
            output_name_template % current_piece
        )
        current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=',')
        current_limit = row_limit
        if keep_headers:
            headers = filehandler.next()
            current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
        for i, row in enumerate(filehandler):
            if i + 1 > current_limit:
                current_piece += 1
                current_limit = row_limit * current_piece
                current_out_path = os.path.join(
                    output_path,
                    output_name_template % current_piece
                )
                current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=',')
                if keep_headers:
                    current_out_writer.writerow(self.headers)
            current_out_writer.writerow(row)

split(self.merged_data)
```

first error

```
 headers = filehandler.next()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Second error

```
for i, row in enumerate(filehandler):
TypeError: 'Merge_project' object is not iterable
```

how to fix the error and split the hash and write out to different csv file?

Comment: What data does `filehandler` hold?

Comment: Which version of `Python` do you use? What is the type of `merged_data`?